# Declaring a variable outside of if statement dosen't work

Tags: c#

I've been trying to find out a way to use a variable outside of an if statement for a while now but the solutions I've found have been declared errors by my computer. Just to give an example, here's some extremely basic that it considers wrong...

```
int fr = 5;

double f = 0;
if (fr == 5)
{
    double f = 2;
}
```

It keeps telling me that variable that's inside the if statement cannot be used and gives me this message

> A local or parameter named 'f' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The error-message is self-explanatory!

Comment: you cant declare a variable with the same name in a outer scope, and then in a inner scope

Comment: You are declaring `f` twice, that's what is going wrong. Simply remove `double` and it works - but you change the value of the earlier defines `f`.

Comment: `double f = fr == 5 ? 2 : 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
int fr = 5;
double f = 0;

if (fr == 5)
{
    double f = 2;
}
```

you redefine f in the if, just remove the word double to make it f=2
After the if f will either be 0 or 2

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my stupidity, I'm learning C# in high school and the way they teach it sucks. But there's another problem, let's say I were to use f in an equation or another if statement or simply want to put Console.WriteLine("{0}", f};. It now tells me that the variable is unassigned.

Comment: With the code you showed it would be initialized.  I taught myself c# (and a number of other languages and didnt  have the internet for any bar c#) so grab a book and read that.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'm just trying to pass the school year so I may not follow that last suggestion, but maybe I will if I ever find the time.

Comment: most language basics wont take you more than a week if you spend an hour a day!